# How to query Facebook Graph API correctly in Google Apps Script using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I am attempting to retrieve a set of information for a specific link (https://www.theverge.com/2019/10/25/20932653/facebook-news-breitbart-mark-zuckerberg-statement-bias) from the Facebook Graph API using Google Apps Script.

I can get the information by using the following URL (access key removed):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/?id=https://www.theverge.com/2019/10/25/20932653/facebook-news-breitbart-mark-zuckerberg-statement-bias&fields=og_object{title,description,site_name,id,image},engagement&metadata=1&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But when I try to use the following code in Google Script Editor, I receive an error:

```
function myFunction() {


  var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/';
  var params = {
    "method": 'GET',
    "id":"https://www.theverge.com/2019/10/25/20932653/facebook-news-breitbart-mark-zuckerberg-statement-bias",
    "fields":"og_object{title,description,site_name,id,image},engagement",
    "access-token": 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      };

    // Call the Facebook API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);


  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.log(json);

}
```

Error:

```
Request failed for https://graph.facebook.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api","type"... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 15, file "Code")
```

How can I make the request correctly and return the JSON response?

Comment: Have you done what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: I'm reading the GraphAPI docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/) , but I have not been able to work out how to edit my code to make a valid 'GET' request using the UrlFetchApp.fetch method.

Comment: @karpathy Look up and read the documentation for `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. You are not using the method as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are attempting to access the [`URL Node`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/url) of the Graph API:

- You should remove the `fields` specified in your request that are not specified in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/url). Those are: `site_name` and `image`.
- You should include the query string directly in the URL of the request. Notice that the `params` argument of the URLFetch's [`fetch(url, params)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) is not the query string, but rather some specific parameters described in the documentation.

A possible modification of your code fixing the points detailed above could look as follows:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var base_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/?id=%s&fields=%s&access_token=%s';

  var id_param = encodeURIComponent("https://www.theverge.com/2019/10/25/20932653/facebook-news-breitbart-mark-zuckerberg-statement-bias");
  var fields_param = encodeURIComponent("og_object{title,description,site_name,id,image},engagement");
  var access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  var url = Utilities.formatString(base_url, id_param, fields_param, access_token);

    // Call the Facebook API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);


  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.log(json);

}
```

#### Reference - functions used

- [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
- [`Utilities.formatString()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate,-args)
- [`URLFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)